# Non-existence of a prime generating polynomial recurrence relation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $f\in \mathbb{Q} [x]$ be a polynomial, and $a_0 = a$ be an arbitrary integer. Let us define a sequence $\{a_n \} $ by the recurrence relationship : $$a_n = f(a_{n-1} ). $$ I want to show that $a_n $ cannot always be a prime number, with $\{a_n \}$ being pairwise distinct. I am pretty sure that this is a very well known fact, but I cannot easily find this.

Comment: Note : I posted this question on mathoverflow.
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/225722/non-existence-of-a-prime-generating-polynomial-recurrence-relation

Answer (score 1):

For the case when $f(x)=ax+b$ is of first degree, then $a_n$ is a recurrent sequence. See the following paper by J.Berstel (in French) : Une application d'un théorème de Mahler....Comptes Rendus Acad Sciences Paris, 01-04-1968, t. 266, serie A, p 693-695. Let $\tau(x)$ the number of divisors of $x\in \mathbb{Z}$.  He show that for a recurrent sequence $a_n\in \mathbb{Z}$, if $\tau(a_n)$ is bounded, (and this is the case if $a_n$ is prime for large $n$) then the  sequence $a_n$ is bounded, and $a_n$ is ultimately periodic.

See also Erdos, Maxsein, Smith, Analysis, t.10,71-83, 1990.